# The correct way of error handling in PHP

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP development, and now i am following a tutorial but i am little bit confused with error handling implementation in this tutorial.

i am making registration process, here is a function to register a new user to the database

```
function registerUser($username,$password,$email,$fullname) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO users SET username=?, password=?,email=?,fullname=?";
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if (!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        }

        $statement-> bind_param('ssss',$username,$password,$email,$fullname);
        $returnValue = $statement -> execute();


        return $returnValue;
    }
```

the implementation of this `registerUser` function

```
// making connection
$file = parse_ini_file("../../../host.ini");
$dbhost = trim($file["host"]); 
$dbusername = trim($file["username"]);
$dbpassword = trim($file["password"]);
$dbname = trim($file["dbname"]);


$access = new access($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
$access->connect();



// Inserting user to database
$result = $access->registerUser($username,$securedPassword,$email,$fullname);

if ($result) {

    $user = $access->selectUser($username);

    $resultArray = [

        "status" => "200",
        "message" => "Sucessfully registered",
        "id" => $user["id"],
        "username" => $user["username"],
        "email" => $user["email"],
        "avatar" => $user["avatar"],
        "fullname" => $user["fullname"]
    ];

} else{

    $resultArray = [
        "status" => "400",
        "message" => "can't insert data to database "
    ];

}

$access->disconnect();

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

I don't understand when `throw new Exception($statement->error);` will be used. because there is no echo when the error happened. why do i have to add this line of code in the `registerUser` function

as far as i know, if i want to throw exception, it should be in the this format

```
try {
} catch {
}
```

should I change to try and catch format ? or is it ok to use throw exception in if statement like that?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the try and catch block, however, they are only used when you want to catch an error and deal with it specially (in most of the cases, show more informative error message). Without doing that (like the way you present it in the code) the script will terminate by the apache's top level error handeller.

So in brief, if you want to make a custom error handeller you need a try catch block, otherwise, just throw error whenever needed.